# Webdriver test fails with ElementNotVisibleException while running through cc.net

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium, cruisecontrol.net, cruisecontrol

I have a simple test which is opening the page, clicking one button and clicking the next button in the appeared light box (I'm finding the elements by id). 
I can run this test in Visual Studio and it passes successfully for IE and Chrome browsers, but when I try to force it from CuiseControl.Net it fails for IE with the following exception:

```
Test Error : WilcoWebClient.WebdriverTests.RequestTest(IE).TestCreateRequest
OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotVisibleException : Element is not displayed
```

Could anyone help me to find out why it fails?

I am using:

- Windows Server 2008 R2
- Selenium.WebDriver 2.39.0
- Selenium.WEbDriver.IEDriver 2.35.3.3 WebDriver.ChromeDriver.win32
- Cruise Control: Version : 1.8.4.0

Comment: Update your IEDriver is step 1. Step 2 is ensuring the protected mode settings are correctly set on both machines. Step 3 is showing us the code that you are using that fails on the CI server, step 4 is explaining what AJAX, animations and JavaScript occur through the page, step 5 is showing us the HTML that you are dealing with, step 6 is implementing a basic explicit wait, waiting to ensure the element becomes visible and finally step 7 is thinking about whether or not the user has to do anything special to make it visible.

Answer (score 0):

I've installed selenium server and it helped. Here is the piece of my code:

```
public enum Browser
{
    IE,
    CHROME,
    REMOTE_IE,
};

private IWebDriver CreateWebdriver(Browser browser)
    {
        IWebDriver driver = null;
        switch (browser)
        {
            case Browser.IE:
                InternetExplorerOptions ieOptions = new InternetExplorerOptions();
                ieOptions.IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings = true;
                ieOptions.RequireWindowFocus = true;
                driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(ieOptions);
                break;
            case Browser.CHROME:
                driver = new ChromeDriver();
                break;
            case Browser.REMOTE_IE:
                driver = new RemoteWebDriver(
                    new Uri(Utils.BASE_URL + ":4444/wd/hub"), 
                    DesiredCapabilities.InternetExplorer());
                break;
        }
        if (driver == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Couldn't initialize WebDriver for browser " + browser.ToString());
        }
        return driver;
    }
```